# How to create a priority logic for email in SFMC based on data

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions, sql, automation

**Current Use-case:**

We have a data extension with the following fields:

| CustomerID | Customer_EmailAddress | Customer_Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john@test.com | Category_101 |
| 1 | john@test.com | Category_202 |
| 2 | lee@test.com | Category_101 |
| 3 | mike@test.com | Category_202 |

We have an automation that runs a query daily something like this and trigger a dynamic email:

```
Select * from customer_DE where customer_category IN ('Category_101', 'Category_202')
```

The dynamic email includes 2 content blocks something like this:

| EmailFile |
| --- |
| Category_101 block |
| Category_202 block |

In this case, if a customer got category 101 then content block 101 shows up and if a customer got category 202 then content block 202 shows up.

**New requirement:**
We would like to add a priority in the logic, meaning if a customer got multiple records with multiple category then do not trigger multiple email or email with multiple content block.

Goal is the create a priority so final audience query is only picking customer with a higher priority category (IF multiple rows exist with multiple categories)

If this is our priority:

| Priority | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Category_101 |
| 2 | Category_202 |

Goal is for logic / query to create following results.

| CustomerID | Customer_EmailAddress | Customer_Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john@test.com | Category_101 |
| 2 | lee@test.com | Category_101 |
| 3 | mike@test.com | Category_202 |

Any advise / direction / example on how to create a logic for priority list and how to handle this in query and email process? I am assuming, a priority list / table will be needed? what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL [Row_Number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function to deduplicate by emailaddress, order by priority, and only select the top 1 row from each group.

below SQL joins customer and category DE, then partition by email address and assign the a row number for each record for that email order by priority asc, then in the outer SQL, select row number = 1 will select only one record per customer email.

```
Select b.CustomerID
,b.Customer_EmailAddress
,b.Customer_Category
From (
    Select c.CustomerID
    ,c.Customer_EmailAddress
    ,c.Customer_Category
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.Customer_EmailAddress ORDER BY Priority ASC) AS rn
    from customer_DE  c inner join category_DE cat
    on c.Customer_Category = cat.Category
    where c.customer_category IN ('Category_101', 'Category_202')
) b
Where b.rn = 1
```

---

**Update** above SQL query to check and exclude email already exist in target DE, use `NOT IN` to exclude emails already exist in target DE (your Journey entry source DE).

This journey should be set to trigger on automation runs, so you can set automation job to run every day, above query will populate all new records into the target DE and trigger the journey **if** email does not exist in target DE, as well as deduplicate if new records contain the same emailAddress multiple times and pick top one by priority value.

```
Select b.CustomerID
,b.Customer_EmailAddress
,b.Customer_Category
From (
    Select c.CustomerID
    ,c.Customer_EmailAddress
    ,c.Customer_Category
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.Customer_EmailAddress ORDER BY Priority ASC) AS rn
    from customer_DE  c inner join category_DE cat
    on c.Customer_Category = cat.Category
    where c.customer_category IN ('Category_101', 'Category_202')
    and Customer_EmailAddress NOT IN (select Customer_EmailAddress from target_DE
) b
Where b.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you @Bo Hu - one question, if I do not want to de-dup on email address then what should be the difference in the partition by line?

Comment: @kuml2 but you only want to send one version of the email per customer and select the email/content block version by priority right? You can still keep your customer_DE and category_DE DE data. Above SQL is to be exported into a new DE with distinct email per customer with selected priority value, so priority value can be pass into email content block to render personalised content. If you don't deduplicate, the same email may enter multiple times and receive different copies

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll give this a try & report been here if this resolved the use case. Just curious, in case I need to de-dup based on multiple fields like combination of customer ID + Email + Category. I just need to add multiple fields separated by comma in the partition statement, right? In my use case it's a transactioal email so I may get use cases where just de-dup by email not sufficient. Could be de-dup based on product so each product will have an email copy. Something like PARTITION BY c.Customer_EmailAddress, c.customerID, c.customer_category ORDER BY, correct?

Comment: @kuml2 that is correct, 
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Column1],[Column2],[Column3] ORDER BY [Priority] ASC)`

Comment: Thank you so much Bo Hu, I'm def confirm back here after my testing

Comment: @kuml2 no worries let me know how you go

Comment: Hi Bo Hu, one question, the priority is only applicable if multiple categories shows up in the audience list at a given day, right? If customer shows up first with category "Category_101" on day 1 in the audience and Category_102 on day 7, Is there any way to NOT trigger email for 102? also vice versa,, if customers first shows up with 102 (in which case email will be triggered since no prioritization applies) but then same customers shows up later with 101, if goal is to not trigger multiple emails.

Comment: @kuml2 hi, sure, I have updated the query to exclude email if already exists in target DE

Comment: Hi Bo Hu thank you for your response. Do you mind posting both versions of code please? Just so I can understand the difference. That would help me to learn the approach. Thanks again

Comment: @kuml2 sure, updated, just one line code difference

Comment: @kuml2 if this answer helps you please mark it as accepted

Comment: Hi Bo Hu - Absolutely, thank you so much for your help and guidance with the logic.